# uwsgi django1.3.5 error: "is outside repository"

Tags: django, repository, uwsgi

my application suffered fatal errors, all of the search engines can not find some answer. Please somebody help me. Thank u.

My application run with uwsgi, some fatal error appear in uwsgi log，whenever 'HARAKIRI' triggered or not, always have something like flow：

> Wed Sep 27 01:17:57 2016 - HARAKIRI !!! worker 25 status !!!
>
> Wed Sep 27 01:17:57 2016 - HARAKIRI [core 0] 149.202.48.192 - GET /problem/17800 since 1474391873
>
> Wed Sep 27 01:17:57 2016 - HARAKIRI !!! end of worker 25 status !!!
>
> fatal: '/home/workspace/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mysqlpool/backends/mysqlpool/base.py' is outside repository
>
> fatal: '/home/workspace/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py' is outside repository
>
> fatal: '/home/workspace/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py' is outside repository
>
> fatal: '/home/workspace/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py' is outside repository
>
> fatal: '/home/workspace/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py' is outside repository
>
> fatal: '/home/workspace/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py' is outside repository
>
> fatal: '/home/workspace/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/search/SearchService.py' is outside repository

I don't know how and why something like this， but application is not affected. The flow is my uwsgi conf:

```
<uwsgi>
<socket>:3344</socket>
<pidfile>/home/nb/staticfiles/pids/chunyu-uwsgi.pid</pidfile>
<master/>
<chdir>/home/nb/webapps/propellant</chdir>
<pythonpath>/home/nb/webapps/propellant</pythonpath>
<module>wsgi</module>

<!-- 3s timeout -->
<harakiri>3</harakiri>

<workers>40</workers>

<listen>8192</listen>

<enable-threads/>
<logto>/home/nb/logs/xxoo/chunyu_uwsgi.log</logto>
<daemonize>/home/nb/logs/xxoo/chunyu_uwsgi.log</daemonize>
<memory-report/>

<buffer-size>35535</buffer-size>
<post-buffering>1</post-buffering>

<reload-on-as>1200</reload-on-as>
<reload-on-rss>750</reload-on-rss>
</uwsgi>
```

Comment: Is your app doing something with git? That seems like a git error message.

Comment: No, only when update the project for upgrade, will use git tool. So I'm very confused about this.